# SQL JOIN while concatenating data from subsequent rows

Tags: mysql, join, mysql5

I'm having a hard time trying to puzzle together a query against an older MySQL 5.0 DB. The data model isn't optimal to begin with.

**Data**

| ReceiptID | LineNbr | ProdNbr | Description | PrincipleDescription |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54092 | 1 | 1023 | abc | abc |
| 54092 | 2 | 731 | def | def |
| 54092 | 3 | 617 | ghi | ghi |
| 54092 | 4 | 618 | rst | ghi |
| 54092 | 5 | 692 | xyz | ghi |
| 54092 | 6 | 331 | jkl | jkl |
| 54092 | 7 | 608 | mno | mno |
| 54092 | 8 | 618 | rst | mno |
| 54092 | 9 | 1040 | ahd | ahd |

The Description values rst, xyz are prefixed with two space characters thus stored in the DB as e.g. '  rst'. These are added comments/notes to the preceding line item that ain't prefix with spaces.

**Expected Output**:

| ReceiptID | LineNbr | ProdNbr | DESCRIPTION | PrincipleDescription |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54092 | 1 | 1023 | abc | abc |
| 54092 | 2 | 731 | def | def |
| 54092 | 3 | 617 | ghi | ghi (rst, xyz) |
| 54092 | 6 | 331 | jkl | jkl |
| 54092 | 7 | 608 | mno | mno (rst) |
| 54092 | 9 | 1040 | ahd | ahd |

I was thinking LEAD() or alike could help out here but that only got introduced since MySQL 8 thus that ain't available for my use case. Any other ways I could achieve such result instead?

Comment: Based on the sample data you could use the PrincipalDescription field to group by on and use group_concat() to produce the expected outcome. The question is: would this logic work for the real data?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5, you can use variables to store values of your fields, then change variables values any time there's a change in either "*ReceiptID*" or "*PrincipleDescription*" fields. Once you have selected your first values fields for both "*LineNbr*" and "*ProdNbr*", you can apply aggregation.

```
SET @receiptID   = '';
SET @lineNbr     = -1; 
SET @prodNbr     = -1;
SET @descr       = '';

SELECT ReceiptID,
       LineNbr,
       ProdNbr, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(Description) AS DESCRIPTION,
       PrincipleDescription
FROM (SELECT IF(ReceiptID = @receiptID AND PrincipleDescription = @descr, 
                @lineNbr, @lineNbr := LineNbr         ) AS LineNbr,
             IF(ReceiptID = @receiptID AND PrincipleDescription = @descr, 
                @prodNbr, @prodNbr := ProdNbr         ) AS ProdNbr,
             Description,
             IF(ReceiptID = @receiptID AND @descr = PrincipleDescription,
                @descr, @descr := PrincipleDescription) AS PrincipleDescription,
             IF(ReceiptID = @receiptID, 
                @receiptID, @receiptID := ReceiptID   ) AS ReceiptID
      FROM tab) cte
GROUP BY ReceiptID,
         LineNbr,
         ProdNbr, 
         PrincipleDescription
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7UT2GrV7ZKYR54LwwkEUiv/1).

---

In MySQL 8, you can first select the needed values with the [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value) window function, then aggregate the "*Description*" on the other fields:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ReceiptID, 
           FIRST_VALUE(LineNbr) OVER(
               PARTITION BY ReceiptID, PrincipleDescription
               ORDER     BY LineNbr                         ) AS LineNbr,
           FIRST_VALUE(ProdNbr) OVER(
               PARTITION BY ReceiptID, PrincipleDescription
               ORDER     BY LineNbr                         ) AS ProdNbr,
           FIRST_VALUE(Description) OVER(
               PARTITION BY ReceiptID, PrincipleDescription
               ORDER     BY LineNbr                         ) AS Description,
           Description                                        AS PrincipleDescription
    FROM tab
)
SELECT ReceiptID, LineNbr, ProdNbr, Description,
       GROUP_CONCAT(PrincipleDescription) AS PrincipleDescription 
FROM cte
GROUP BY ReceiptID, LineNbr, ProdNbr, Description
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7UT2GrV7ZKYR54LwwkEUiv/0).